# Creating multi module project using Intellij & Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project structure which has a core tool and a REST API to interact and configure that tool.

I have a package structure like this:

```
com.example.api -> contains API definitions
com.example.commons -> contains module common to both core and api
com.exmaple.core -> contains the core module
```

This is primarily a Spring Boot application and both will run in different containers. So the API and the Core jar will be different.

How do I create a multi-module project with this structure so that I can also use the commons module in both the sub packages(core & api). 
Suggestions on how to configure Maven and IntelliJ in such an environment?

Is my pattern right? Are there other well known patterns for this kind of project structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a multi Maven module project as you wish. Here's an example on how you should configure your modules:

Create a parent `pom.xml` as follows (note that I am not adding `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent to the project, I am bringing in the Spring Boot dependencies with `spring-boot-dependencies`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>example-commons</module>
        <module>example-core</module>
        <module>example-api</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And a non executable module's `pom.xml` would be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>example-commons</artifactId>

</project>
```

whereas an executable module's `pom.xml` would be like (note the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is present only here for this dependency):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```